# Using Resource (.resx) files in kendo ui grid with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, resx

Is it possible using resource files (.resx) for naming convention for kendo ui grid with angularjs? I am not use razor html for my view, just only javascript file.
For example, this is my part of code:

```
columns: [{
            field: "FieldName",
            title: "Resources.MyResourceFile.NameString", //use resource file for column convention
            width: 50
        }, ...
```

Resources.MyResourceFile is file and path for my resource file. NameString is value in my resource file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid this behaviour is not supported. If you want change title based on resources you will have to create your own helper function which will return texts. Idea is that for every column will be called same function (in javascript) and this function will ajax server and return text based on resources? (or if you will have better idea)

Here is small [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe/6) to know how I am meaning this.